# HybridAuth not authenticating when using custom php session path

Tags: php, session, hybridauth

I have an issue when using the [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) plugin. I have included the plugin as a popup in in my home page. When clicking on the login button from home page the plugin will load in colorbox.

In my server I can't use default php session save path so that I have set it as php temp path for saving session like below in index.php of my root folder.

```
$dir = sys_get_temp_dir();
session_save_path($dir);
```

After updating this code, the plugin is authenticating the social media that customer selecting successfully and return back to my site, but it is not passing the below condition,

```
$hybridauth->isConnectedWith( $_GET["connected_with"] ) // it is always return false
```

In second case I have updated the session save path in index.php of plugin folder also, but at at that time in the login popup instead of showing login UI it is directly showing an error page like below

```
"You cannot access this page directly."
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also getting same error. Can anyone provide a quick fix for this?

Comment: @user2916075: May be it's not storing the user session which you tried to login. Did you check whether the session exists after redirecting to your site?

Comment: [Turn on debugging](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Debugging_and_Logging.html) and give us a chance to see what the API is saying the problem is.  I'm willing to bet you'll see `PHP session.name diff from default PHPSESSID.`

Comment: what this error message means?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your default session path:

```
$dir = sys_get_temp_dir();
session_save_path($dir);
```

I would print_r sessions to see what got registered. Why do you have issues with default session path? I wouldn't try to alter it and make sure that works first. This is altering the main functionality of HybridAuth.

Why can't you use the default php session save path? are you on a shared host?

--

If you have shell access make sure the web server user has write access to the directory; that should take care of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As often : [RTM and discover the use of isConnectedWith](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/apidoc.html)

> **isConnectedWith()**
>   Return a true or false if the current user is connected to a given
>   provider. Hybrid_Auth::isConnectedWith() use PHP Sessions. To know
>   more refer to the HybridAuth Sessions section.

```
Hybrid_Auth::isConnectedWith(provider)
```

Where **provider** is the name of the tested service. eg : **Hybrid_Auth::isConnectedWith('Twitter')**

Be sure that your $_GET returns the good service name.

If you want a list of connected providers : **Hybrid_Auth::getConnectedProviders()**

If you want to inspect session's datas : **Hybrid_Auth::getSessionData()**

API !

Answer (score 0):

Add your own custom session handler at the top of `hybridauth/index.php` (located in the same dir as `config.php` and `live.php`).
This forces Hybrid Auth to use your custom session handler.